# Why does the contact form not update? Question about problem from official react docs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state

Was going through the official react docs and saw the Challenge 3 of 5: Reset a detail form

In this the contents of edit contact form does not update when you flip through the buttons above,

The official explanation is that the form does not change because it is rendered in the same dom position.

My question. Since the state in the edit contact form has changed shouldnt it refresh the form to display latest values? Can understand why the form does not reset in previous examples but in this casethe form has to reload with latest values correct? Any ideas

Was expecting the edit contact form to refresh with latest values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since the state in the edit contact form has changed shouldnt it refresh the form to display latest values?

The state hasn't changed. In that challenge, they're doing

```
<EditContact initialData={selectedContact} onSave={handleSave} />
```

and

```
export default function EditContact({ initialData, onSave }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState(initialData.name);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(initialData.email);
```

, i.e. "forking" the `initialData` prop to state. Recall that the values passed to `useState()` are the initial values only used when mounting the component; since only the prop changes (and the component doesn't remount), the (changed) data from `initialData` doesn't get copied to those state atoms.

Comment: thanks akx. I checked that the data passed to the edit contact does change by printing it out in the edit contact. My question is if the prop to a component changes shouldnt the component rerender? isnt that the contract for react, that if a prop changes the component should rerender with new state

Comment: What did you print out? `name` and `email` or `initialData`?

Comment: initial data. but if that prop changes it should rerender is what i understood , since it says components will rerender when props change

Comment: Does `EditContact` use `initialData` in the rendered output? I doubt it.

Comment: You are correct it dosent use initialData in output. I  was under the impression that if you rerender editcontact it would run the code from top to bottom and since prop has changed it will run setState code and update it and use it for rendering. Apparently my understanding is wrong

Comment: Why would it run any setState? As my answer explains, the initial state passed to useState is only ever read when the component mounts, not when props change.